# Past Simple + Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect

My teacher said it is impossible to use Past Simple with Present Perfect. What about this example:

I went shopping [today/yesterday] to improve my mood but instead I ... sad.

Should I use became or have become? I want to emphasize I am still sad.

or is it better to say:

I went shopping and I am sad.

Comment: _But_ connects one clause with another. The past tense is in one clause and the perfect construction would be in another clause, so it's not being "used with" (though that's a pretty sloppy way to state a rule, imo). There is no rule against using them together; it just happens that the situations where one is suitable are rarely situations where the other one would work. The Perfect construction has a number of requirements, but past tense is much more general in its application and may apply where Perfect also works.

Comment: What about I've been doing shopping because I wanted to improve my mood but I've been sad? Does this sound natural?

Comment: No. You'd say _I've been shopping_. "Doing shopping" is not idiomatic. The amended sentence is strange and confusing because there are potentially two time periods referred to -- have you been sad only since you started shopping, or is the sadness the "mood" you wanted to improve?

Comment: I went shopping and I am become sad.

Answer (score 0):

For every rule, there is an exception....

> Example of Simple Past used in a sentence with Present Perfect: "I debugged my program today, and have now completed all my coursework for the semester!"